# How do I add a script just above the closing body tag?

Tags: 8, theming, javascript

### How do I add a script on Drupal 8 site/app just above closing body tag?

Vendor provided some JS in the following form:

```js
<script>
    ... code
</script>
```

Asked me to place immediately above `</body>`.

**The script was only to run for Anonymous traffic.**

Here's how I did it:

THEME = name of your theme

1. Removed `<script>` and `</script>` from code
2. Minified using https://javascript-minifier.com/
3. Created file name-of-my-script.min.js
4. Uploaded to THEME/js/custom/name-of-my-script.min.js
5. Added library to bottom of THEME.libraries.yml

```js
name-of-my-library:
  version: 1.0
  js:
    js/custom/name-of-my-script.min.js: {preprocess: false} // {preprocess: false} is responsible for code showing up above </body>
```

6. Added the following code to THEME.theme to an already existing function: `function THEME_preprocess_page(&$variables) {}`

```js
$logged_in = $variables['logged_in'];
    if (!$logged_in) {
    $variables['#attached']['library'][] = 'THEME/name-of-my-library';
}
```

7. Cleared cache.

### Resourses that helped:

- https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/javascript-api/add-javascript-to-your-theme-or-module
- https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/creating-custom-modules/adding-stylesheets-css-and-javascript-js-to-a-drupal-8-module

Comment: I see that I need to escape the closing body tag. I don't have edit access (even though I created post) so could admin please help with that? Tahnks.

Comment: Your script get's aggregated by Drupal's core. You will not see it in the rendered page output. You may change the aggregation on /admin/config/development/performance.

Comment: By adding `{ preprocess: false }` property, the script does not get aggregated:

https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming/adding-stylesheets-css-and-javascript-js-to-a-drupal-8-theme#js-properties

Comment: What is your question - does your code solve the problem?

Comment: I was told that asking and answering my own question was a good way to help others on StackExchange; this was my first offering.

I'd edit the post but I no longer see the edit button.

All I have to do is change the heading from 'How to..." to "How do I".

Comment: I found the edit link and made the change to question. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: Where does this requirement come from? Some library telling you to do it that way? It's probably just fine to have it added to the footer by default.

Comment: Please don't add the answer to the question. Please add it as answer below.

Comment: There are many ways to add a library to a Drupal 8 website. This is one way; maybe someone will share a different way - and we'll all learn something new.

"How do I add a script on Drupal 8 site/app just above closing body tag?" is the/a question. Respectfully,

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this simply by using jquery. If you want to access it from all theme pages you need to add the below line in your global common js file which has access to all the theme pages in the app.

```
$('body').append('<script src="/name-of-your-library"></script>');
```